# How can I query a model by association, but still access all of the model's associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

To get the results of a search, I query with

```
Shop.all
.includes(:tags)
.where('tags.name ilike ?', "%#{query}%")
.references(:tags)
```

Then display it with

```
<%= render :partial => "shop_card", :collection => @shops, :as => :shop %>
```

and in the partial

```
<% shop.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.name  %>
<% end %>
```

Shops and tags have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

When I do this, the partial view only displays the tag I searched for, instead of showing all the tags for that shop. I can't understand why. How do I access all the tags for that shop?

Comment: `shops = Shop.all.includes(:tags)` this will give you all tags

`shops.first.tags` will give you tags for first shop and use loop for all

Comment: @G.B But I cant see why the query is affecting my access to the association. Once I do a query that gets me the shop, shouldn't I be able to do shop.tags and get all that shop's tags regardless of what the query was?

Answer (score 0):

Add condition for search scenario...

```
@shops = Shop
.includes(:tags)
.references(:tags)

if query
   @shops = @shops.where('tags.name ilike ?', "%#{query}%")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do have the query inside the statement `if query.present?`. That isn't related to the problem of accessing the shop's associations.

Comment: When query="", where condition will return only the tags which contains "". This will be empty.. If you need more clarification, please add a full code of this controller method

Comment: But why is the query affecting my ability to access the shop's tags? If I do a query that gives me a shop, shouldn't I then be able to do shop.tags and get all the tags for that shop regardless of what query I got the shop from?

Comment: You are querying inside the tags table. Then how can you see the tags which is not matching the query. I think you intent to query inside the shops table..